# How do I define in the model a class method, not an instance one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, class-method, instance-method

I want to be able to call `Activity.pull_latest` from a controller, but if I do

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def pull_latest [...]
```

I have to call it `Activity.new.pull_latest`.

How do I define in the model a class method, not an instance one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self`:

```
def self.pull_latest
```

Then you can call `Activity.pull_latest`